# Many ways to write the same directive and controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have seen a few different ways to write angular directives and controllers and just wondering which is best practice or which of them are essentially the same. From the below examples I would like to know the benefits of each or if they are the same. IF they are the same what's the advantages of both.

```
//Declare my module app
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);



    app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.customer = {
          name: 'blaa',
          address: 'bla blaaablaa'
        };
      }])
      .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'temp.html'
        };
      });
```

---

***Ok so the first difference is in the above Controller. Here are two ways I have seen them written.***

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

});
```

**or**

```
app.controller('Controller', function($scope){
});
```

The first one uses an array to pass in a $scope plus a function with a scope.
The second one only passes a function with a $scope. 
Why the difference? Why 2 $scopes or are they the same $scope.

---

***Now for the second difference i'm seeing with directives.***

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function() {
            return {
              templateUrl: 'temp.html'
            };
          });
```

**or**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    };
})
```

So what's the difference here apart from one returns a function with scope, element, attrs ?

An now for last question.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.color, function(value) {

            });
        };
    });
```

The above is using a $watch method, doesn't angular already do this with binding. 
For example couldn't I just use the below the same way or '=' for two way binding. Please explain the difference for me.

```
  return {
    scope: {
    color: '@'
    }
```

Hopefully I broke out these 3 questions in a helpfully manner for you all to interoperate and answer me constructively.

Comment: The array syntax is so that minification will not break the dependency injection. The difference in the directive syntax is not as significant, the second form is a shortcut for when the directive just needs a link function. Not sure I can tell you why a $watch versus a bound attribute - seems like they would both do roughly the same thing. An advantage of the watch method is that you can get an unregister function returned from the watch and cancel it at some point if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**

As aet pointed out, the array notation passing the dependencies as strings, is useful for minification. Because your minification tool will convert any variable name, but won't change any string. You can test it by writting something like:

```
['$scope', function(thisShouldBeStillAScope) {
```

And angular will resolve that variable to a $scope.

**Second question**

In a directive, you can specify many elements, and each one has a particular use. If you just want to include a template without any behaviour, you are fine with the first one. If you need to do something like changing a property etc. you will need to do with through the link function. Particularly in directives, you can achieve the exact same thing through different ways, its up to you to find the easiest one.

**Third question**
$watch specifies a function that triggers every time that the value of the variable the directive is watching changes. You will find it useful when you want to watch a $scope variable that hasn't been yet binded by the controller.

Hope it helps.